# How should I free a C# byte[] allocated in Rust?

Tags: c#, rust, ffi

I have a Rust function that passes a byte array to C#:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_bytes(len: &mut i32, bytes: *mut *mut u8) {
    let mut buf : Vec<u8> = get_data();
    buf.shrink_to_fit();

    // Set the output values
    *len = buf.len() as i32;
    unsafe {
        *bytes = buf.as_mut_ptr();
    }

    std::mem::forget(buf);
}
```

From C#, I can call it without crashing. (In lieu of a crash, I *assume* this is correct but am not 100% sure):

```cs
[DllImport("my_lib")] static extern void get_bytes(ref int len, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] ref byte[] bytes);

void test()
{
   int len = 0;
   byte[] bytes = null;
   get_bytes(ref len, ref bytes);
}
```

I then make use of `bytes`, but I understand that this memory needs to be freed by Rust. So I have another Rust function to free it:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn free_bytes(len: i32, bytes: *mut *mut u8) {
    // also tried with: -------------- bytes: *mut u8
    assert!(len > 0);

    // Rebuild the vec
    let v = unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(bytes, len as usize, len as usize) };

    //println!("bytes to free: {:?}", v);

    drop(v); // or it could be implicitly dropped
}
```

And the corresponding C#. Making the call crashes my app:

```cs
[DllImport("my_lib")] extern void free_bytes(int len, ref byte[] bytes);

void test()
{
   int len = 0;
   byte[] bytes = null;
   get_bytes(ref len, ref bytes);

   // copy bytes to managed memory
   bytes[] copy = new byte[len];
   bytes.CopyTo(copy, 0);
   // free the unmanaged memory
   free_bytes(len, ref bytes); // crash occurs when executing this function
}
```

I see that [`Vec::from_parts_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts) "is highly unsafe". Because "`capacity` needs to be the capacity that the pointer was allocated with.", I also tried passing the capacity between Rust & C# without `shrink_to_fit` to preserve length & capacity. That also crashed.

I assume `from_parts_raw` recovers the existing memory on the heap, but I noticed that the byte content in C# (shown in Visual Studio) doesn't match the contents in Rust (via the 'bytes to free' println). So is my error in how I'm recovering the `Vec<u8>` to be freed, in the types Rust is accepting (eg, `*mut u8` vs `*mut *mut u8`), in my C# `DllImport`, somewhere else?

Comment: Is your actual code immediately passing the array back to Rust after copying out of it? If so, wouldn't it be easier to pass a C# byte array to Rust and have Rust copy _into_ it, then neither side ever has to conceptually give up ownership of their respective buffers.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Vec::from_raw_parts(*bytes, len as usize, len as usize)`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth - Assuming that approach is possible, the challenge I would have is that I don't know how many bytes to allocate up-front. I may potentially be able to invoke once to calculate size and invoke again to populate the `byte[]`, but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Main Problem

A `byte*`/`*mut u8` and a `byte[]` are different kinds of object. The latter *must* point to memory managed by the .NET GC. So while it is possible to view a `byte[]` as a `byte*` (while it is pinned), you cannot view an arbitrary `byte*` as a `byte[]`.

I'm not entirely sure what the marshaller is doing in your case, but it is probably something like this:

- Allocate a pointer-sized space, initialized to the null pointer.
- Call the rust method with a pointer to this space as the second parameter.
- Interpret the updated contents of that space as a pointer to a C-style byte array.
- Copy the contents of this array to a newly-allocated managed array.
- Place that managed array in the C# local `bytes`.

As you can see, the array you get in `bytes` is a fresh managed array, with no lasting relation to the pointer written to `*bytes` by Rust. So of course attempting to call `free_bytes` on `bytes` will fail, since it will be marshalled as a pointer to memory managed by the .NET GC and not Rust.

#### A secondary problem

If you intend to free the memory via P/Invoke, there is no way to get around passing the capacity to C# and keeping it around. This is because `Vec::shrink_to_fit` is not guaranteed to reduce `capacity` to `len`, as indicated by [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit). And you *must* have the correct capacity in order to call `Vec::from_raw_parts`.

### Solution

The only reasonable way to pass ownership of a `Vec` to other code is with functions like these on the Rust side.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn get_bytes(len: *mut i32, capacity: *mut i32) -> *mut u8 {
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = get_data();

    *len = buf.len() as i32;
    *capacity = buf.capacity() as i32;

    let bytes = buf.as_mut_ptr();
    std::mem::forget(buf);
    return bytes;
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn free_bytes(data: *mut u8, len: i32, capacity: i32) {
    let v = Vec::from_raw_parts(bytes, len as usize, capacity as usize);
    drop(v); // or it could be implicitly dropped
}
```

And on the C# side, you would have something like this:

```
[DllImport("my_lib")] 
static extern IntPtr get_bytes(out int len, out int capacity);

[DllImport("my_lib")] 
static extern void free_bytes(IntPtr bytes, int len, int capacity);

void test()
{
   int len, capacity;
   IntPtr ptr = get_bytes(out len, out capacity);
   // TODO: use the data in ptr somehow
   free_bytes(ptr, len, capacity);
}
```

You have a few different options for what to put in place of the TODO.

- Use the `IntPtr` as-is, reading data from the array with methods like `Marshal.ReadIntPtr`. I don't recommend this because it is verbose and error-prone, and would prevent the use of most APIs targeting arrays.
- Convert the `IntPtr` to a `byte*` with `(byte*)ptr.ToPointer()` and use the raw `byte*` directly. This might be marginally less verbose than the above, but it's just as error-prone, and many useful APIs do not accept raw pointers.
- Copy data form the `IntPtr` into a managed `byte[]`. This is a little inefficient, but you will have all the advantages of a real managed array, and it will be safe to use the array even after calling `free_bytes` on the original memory. However, if you want to modify the array and have these modifications be visible to Rust, you will have to perform another copy. For this solution, replace the comment with:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, len);
```

- If you are in C# 7.2 or above, you can avoid copying memory with the new `Span<T>` type, which can represent a range of managed or unmanaged memory. Depending on what you plan to do with `bytes`, a `Span<byte>` may be sufficient, as many APIs have been updated to accept spans in recent versions of C#. As the span refers directly to the memory allocated by Rust, any mutations to it will be reflected on the Rust side, and you must not attempt to use it after that memory has been freed by the call to `free_bytes`. For this solution, replace the comment with:

```
Span<byte> bytes = new Span<byte>(ptr.ToPointer(), len);
```

### A note about safety

Note that the Rust function `get_bytes` is marked as `unsafe`. This is because the `as` operator is used to cast the length and capacity of the vec to `i32`s. This will panic if they do not fit in the range of `i32`, and to the best of my knowledge panicking over an FFI boundary such as that introduced by P/Invoke is still undefined behavior. In production code, `get_bytes` could be modified to handle such errors some other way, perhaps by returning a null pointer, and C# would need to detect this situation and act accordingly.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! `Marshal.Copy` seems to do the. Would the `Span<byte>` approach require `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray...)` to inform .NET about the size of the span?

Comment: The approaches I listed are all based on the same P/Invoke signatures given above. As far as I know, you can't automatically marshal Spans at all, so since the Span does not (cannot) appear in the P/Invoke signature, no `MarshalAs` attribute is necessary. Instead, .NET is informed of the length of the span manually via the `Span<byte>` constructor.

Comment: Oops, just realized I didn't notify you of my reply. @user655321